# Fastest way of writing a file to disk on Linux

Tags: c++, file, optimization, boost, fwrite

Suppose I have a very fast and infinite data source (say a socket, /dev/null or /dev/random) on Linux and I need to write such data to disk in C/C++. What's the fastest code to accomplish that on a given hardware? fwrite(), unbuffered write(), some boost ASIO function?

Comment: A pipe to `gzip -c` can be quite fast.

Comment: Boost ASIO des not have Linux disk io methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in terms of raw output speed, then you're going to have to benchmark it, depending on the test, QoI, platform, what you are writing and a hole host of other things any of FILE, fstreams or POSIX primitives can be the fastest.

However, if you can use something like Boost asio, then you might get a percieved speed up due to it's asynchronous nature, it can get on with the next work read whilst it's still writing to disk.

EDIT: I would go with boost asio, it will allow you to best utilise your resources whilst waiting for inherently slow operations (File and network IO).